# sqlsrv not working despite having a proper install

Tags: php7

I have installed (again) the sqlsrv using pecl for Ubuntu 18 yet for some reason the driver is not found.

This is the error I get `could not find driver`.

Here are the steps I followed:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove php-common
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install php-fpm php-mbstring php-zip php-mysql php-sqlite3 php-dev php-pear php-xml


$ sudo pecl uninstall sqlsrv
$ sudo pecl uninstall pdo_sqlsrv

$ sudo pecl install sqlsrv
$ sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

I created the file sqlsrv.ini with the content:

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

and copied it to `/etc/php/7.2/cli/` and `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/`

here is how the php code looks:

```
$host = "station\SQL, port"; //azure
$db = "dbname";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$db;LoginTimeout=60", $user, $pass);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

When trying to list the modules from the cli with `php -m | grep sql` I don't get the sqlsrv module in the list of loaded modules:

```
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
sqlite3
```

Alternatively `php --ri pdo_sqlsrv` returns `Extension 'pdo_sqlsrv' not present.`

`odbcinst -j` returns:

```
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

`dpkg-query -L libodbc1` returns:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libnn.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libodbc1
/usr/share/doc/libodbc1/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libodbc1/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libodbc1/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libodbc1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.2
```

Comment: I think you're missing the step `2.1` [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/step/2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Enable the mod:
`sudo phpenmod sqlsrv`

See this link to install driver:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017